# AngularJs Valdr : why adding + sign to email address passes validation?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to use AngularJs Valdr plugin, but I realized that when adding + sign to email address, the validation passes.

What I mean is, I have an input with name email, and valdr-type is email.
When I enter something like, email@example.com, it passes (which is OK), but changing to +email@example.com also passes the validation.

Same for an email without domain extension (eg. email@example)

Any idea please ?

Thank you !

Comment: email@example is a valid email address to me, also with + sign or - or _

Answer (score 0):

Per Valdr documentation:

```
https://github.com/netceteragroup/valdr#email
```

email

Checks that the field contains a valid e-mail address. It uses the same regular expression as AngularJS is using for e-mail validation.

Per angularjs documentation:

```
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Bemail%5D
```

"Note: input[email] uses a regex to validate email addresses that is derived from the regex used in Chromium. If you need stricter validation (e.g. requiring a top-level domain), you can use ng-pattern or modify the built-in validators (see the Forms guide) "